# Convert DataFrame Format

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have my dataframe in below format -

```
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- epoch: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

and convert into having multiple values-

```
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- epoch: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Example:

From:

```
1,12345, [pq -> r, ab -> c]
```

To:

```
1,12345, pq ,r
1,12345, ab ,c
```

I am trying this code but doesn't work-

```
val array2Df = array1Df.flatMap(line =>
              line.getMap[String, String](2).map(
                (line.getString(0),line.getString(1),_)
            ))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following

```
 val arrayData = Seq(
      Row("1","epoch_1",Map("epoch_1_key1"->"epoch_1_val1","epoch_1_key2"->"epoch_1_Val2")),
      Row("2","epoch_2",Map("epoch_2_key1"->"epoch_2_val1","epoch_2_key2"->"epoch_2_Val2"))
    )    

 val arraySchema = new StructType()
      .add("Id",StringType)
      .add("epoch", StringType)
      .add("data", MapType(StringType,StringType))

  val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(arrayData),arraySchema)
  df.printSchema()
  df.show(false)
```

[image]

After that you need to explode based on data column. Don't forget to

> **import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode**

```
df.select($"Id",explode($"data")).show(false)
```

[image]